# After an update a document stopped compiling due to babel

Tags: pdftex, babel

I've written a document in my laptop (I have Debian and I use KDE and Kile as my latex editor)

This is my header:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

However after an update to the texlive packagages now every time I compile (pdflatex) Kile opens up the babel.sty to this line:

```
\ifx\bbl@main@language\@undefined
  \bbl@error{%
    You haven't specified a language option}{%
    You need to specify a language, either as a global option\\%
    or as an optional argument to the \string\usepackage\space
    command;\\%
    You shouldn't try to proceed from here, type x to quit.}
\fi
```

The pdf is generated but any spanish options are not used. I don't understand what can be happening. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you test with another language?

Comment: Install the language package: `texlive-lang-all` (Ubuntu) or `texlive-collection-langeuropean` (openSUSE)

Comment: I'm afraid you have incurred in a faulty update.

Comment: Yes!!! Thank you Herbert!! Apparently the updating unisntalled the lang-spanish package. Reinstalling it (just that one because it was the only one I was interested in) solved my problem. Thank you!!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is caused by a faulty update.

Comment: @MartinSchröder Actually the question **is** [on topic](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Quoting from the hlpe center: "If you have a question about ... Distributions like TeX Live, MiKTeX, and MacTeX ... then you're in the right place to ask your question!". A faulty update of a TeX distribution *is* on topic by this definition. (I had the same problem now, and I would *never* thought of searching SuperUser or StackOverflow for this TeX error. The obvious place is TeX.SE)

Comment: @Bakuriu We use 'off topic' to close questions which boil down to 'update your TeX system' or 'reinstall your faulty TeX system'. Historically we used to call these 'too localized', but StackExchange removed this option. The reason for closing is that each question of this type comes down usually to a discussion followed by 'update'/'reinstall', which doesn't make for a good answer in a wiki-like way.